# NuGet Pack - The 'targetFramework' attribute is not declared

Tags: c#, nuget, teamcity

I'm trying to convert a project in my solution to a nuget package. I threw in a .nuspec that was edited from another nuget package I've created, and all seems to be pointing to the correct stuff. My project clearly has a "target Framework" set under properties to 4.6.2, yet when I run my package to pack I'm getting the 'targetFramework' attribute not declared error. I'll post the logs here if you think it'll help. (Also worth mentioning that I'm doing this through TeamCity's nuget CLI build step)

Here's my sanitized nuspec:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>PROJECTNAME.WebUI</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>PROJECTNAME.WebUI</title>
    <authors>COMPANYNAME</authors>
    <owners>COMPANYNAME</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>PROJECTNAME.WebUI</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018, COMPANYNAME</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="AntiXSS" version="4.2.1" targetFramework="net462" />
      <dependency id="Aspose.Cells" version="8.7.0" targetFramework="net462" />
      <dependency id="Aspose.Email" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net462" />
      <dependency id="Aspose.Pdf" version="11.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
      <dependency id="Aspose.Words" version="16.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
      <dependency id="CuteEditor" version="6.7.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
      <dependency id="EO.Pdf" version="15.3.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
  </files>
</package>
```

Comment: What is your nuget version? Did you try it with `Verbosity` set to `detailed`?

Comment: I have not, do you think that'll make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation about dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element).

You can specify multiple targets with this syntax

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>PROJECTNAME.WebUI</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>PROJECTNAME.WebUI</title>
    <authors>COMPANYNAME</authors>
    <owners>COMPANYNAME</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>PROJECTNAME.WebUI</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018, COMPANYNAME</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net462">
        <dependency id="AntiXSS" version="4.2.1" />
        <dependency id="Aspose.Cells" version="8.7.0" />
        <dependency id="Aspose.Email" version="6.2.0" />
        <dependency id="Aspose.Pdf" version="11.3.0" />
        <dependency id="Aspose.Words" version="16.1.0" />
        <dependency id="CuteEditor" version="6.7.1.1" />
        <dependency id="EO.Pdf" version="15.3.1.0" />        
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
  </files>
</package>
```

Or, if it is a simple library with no differences among targets, then do not make any reference to the target framework.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>PROJECTNAME.WebUI</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>PROJECTNAME.WebUI</title>
    <authors>COMPANYNAME</authors>
    <owners>COMPANYNAME</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>PROJECTNAME.WebUI</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018, COMPANYNAME</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="AntiXSS" version="4.2.1" />
      <dependency id="Aspose.Cells" version="8.7.0" />
      <dependency id="Aspose.Email" version="6.2.0" />
      <dependency id="Aspose.Pdf" version="11.3.0" />
      <dependency id="Aspose.Words" version="16.1.0" />
      <dependency id="CuteEditor" version="6.7.1.1" />
      <dependency id="EO.Pdf" version="15.3.1.0" />        
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
  </files>
</package>
```

Comment: Helps clean my code up! But still getting error'd out with the same " 'targetFramework' attribute is not declared "

Comment: Actually I did this and it magically works. Not sure why, but thank you?